# String concatenation not working in Fortran

Tags: string, fortran, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a subroutine which concatenates strings in order to create file names so I can track solution change over nonlinear iterations. It doesn't appear to work however. I've used this code snippet before with no problems so I wonder if maybe this relies on certain compiler flags? The string concatenation portion is at the bottom, and I return the following:

output_name:PLT/Res
filename1:
PLT/Res
filename2:
PLT/Res
Writing to File...           0

Which shows clearly that my string is not concatenated.
I call the subroutine with:

```
   IF (MOD(counter, plot_freq) == 0) call plotSolution(2, counter, 'PLT/Solution', Mesh, W)
```

And the routine is below.

```
subroutine plot_nodal_field(opt, iter, output_file, Mesh, Q)
   use Globals_module,  only : c_in
   use inputs_module,   only : p_in, gamma, rho_in, M_inf
!--------------------------------------------end of use--------------------------------------------!
   integer(i4),     intent(in) :: iter, opt
   type(Mesh_Type), intent(in) :: Mesh
   character(*),    intent(in) :: output_file
   real(dp),        intent(in) :: Q(Mesh%numFields, Mesh%numNodes)
!------------------------------------------end of intents------------------------------------------!
   integer(i4)   :: elem_id,n1,n2,n3
   character(80) :: filename, file_num
   integer(i4)   :: iunit
   integer(i4)   :: n,io, i
   real(dp)      :: x, y, rho, rhoU, rhoV, rhoE, u, v, P, CP, c, MachNum, s
!------------------------------------------end of declare------------------------------------------!


  iunit = 2

  write(file_num,'(I6.6)') iter
  write(*,*) 'output_name:', output_file
  filename = adjustl(trim(output_file)) // '_' // adjustl(trim(file_num)) // '.plt'
  write(*,'(A)') 'filename1:', filename
  filename = adjustl(trim(filename))
  write(*,'(A)') 'filename2:', filename
  print*,'# Writing to File...', iter

   open(unit = iunit, file = filename, status = 'replace', iostat = io)
   if( io /= 0) then
       print*,'ERROR: Opening 2nd order plt file'
   else
       if (opt == 1) then 
           write(iunit,'(A)')  'VARIABLES = "x","y","rho","U","V","P","MachNum","entropy"'
       elseif(opt == 2) then
           write(iunit,'(A)')  'VARIABLES = "x","y","rho","U","V","P"'
   end if
       write(iunit,'(A7, I, A3, I, A41)')  'ZONE N=', Mesh%numNodes, ' E=', Mesh%numTri, ' DATAPACKING=POINT ZONETYPE=FETRIANGLE'
       do i = 1, Mesh%numNodes
           x    = Mesh%nodeCoords(1, i)
           y    = Mesh%nodeCoords(2, i)
           if (opt == 1) then
               rho  = Q(1, i)
               U = Q(2, i)
               V = Q(3, i)
               P = Q(4, i)
               c = sqrt(gamma*P/Q(1,i))
               MachNum = sqrt(Q(2,i)**2 + Q(3,i)**2)/c
               s = P/Q(1,i)**gamma - P_in/rho_in**gamma

               write(iunit,'(8ES)') Real(x), Real(y), Real(Q(1,i)), Real(Q(2,i)), Real(Q(3,i)), Real(Q(4,i)), &
               & Real(MachNum), Real(s)
           elseif (opt == 2) then
               write(iunit,'(6ES)') Real(x), Real(y), Real(Q(1,i)), Real(Q(2,i)), Real(Q(3,i)), Real(Q(4,i))
           end if
     
       end do
       do i = 1, Mesh%numTri
           write(iunit,'(3I)') Mesh%trilist(1,i), Mesh%trilist(2,i), Mesh%trilist(3,i) 
       end do
   end if
   close(iunit)

end subroutine
```

## EDIT:

I tried to make a minimum verifiable example:

```
program plotSolution                                                                                                        
!--------------------------------------------end of use--------------------------------------------!
integer       :: iter
character(80) :: filename
!------------------------------------------end of intents------------------------------------------!
filename = 'PLT/Solution'
iter = 1
call plot_nodal_field(iter, filename)

contains


subroutine plot_nodal_field(iter, output_file)
!--------------------------------------------end of use--------------------------------------------!
integer,      intent(in) :: iter
character(*), intent(in) :: output_file
!------------------------------------------end of intents------------------------------------------!
character(80) :: filename, file_num
integer       :: iunit
!------------------------------------------end of declare------------------------------------------!


iunit = 2

write(file_num,'(I6.6)') iter
write(*,*) 'output_name:', output_file
filename = adjustl(trim(output_file)) // '_' // adjustl(trim(file_num)) // '.plt'
write(*,'(A)') 'filename1:', filename
filename = adjustl(trim(filename))
write(*,'(A)') 'filename2:', filename
print*,'# Writing to File...', iter

open(unit = iunit, file = filename, status = 'replace', iostat = io)
if( io /= 0) then
   print*,'ERROR: Opening 2nd order plt file'
else
end if
close(iunit)
end subroutine
end program
```

But this works:
and returns:

output_name:
PLT/Solution

filename1:
PLT/Solution_000001.plt
filename2:
PLT/Solution_000001.plt
Writing to File...           1
ERROR: Opening 2nd order plt file

which indicates to me I may have some odd memory error in the main code. I'm not sure. Thanks for all the suggestions and help!

Comment: You'd better show us the whole routine, and a wee program you are using to call it.

Comment: The whole routine is long, so I just wanted to put the first part where the issue is taking place. Is it necessary to put the whole routine in?

Comment: Cur the routine down to the relevant bit, add a program to call that, check it demonstrates the problem, and then edit you question to show the whole program. It's much, much, much, much, much, much, much, much, easier to diagnose problems with a complete code

Comment: I included the shortened version of the subroutine. It still prints all the data correctly, but the filename string concatenation still returns the same output.

Comment: A program, please .....

Comment: do the following: 1) write a program which calls `plot_nodal_field`. 2) simplify `plot_nodal_field`, i.e. remove the use module statements, remove `Q,mesh` arguments, remove code between `open` ... `close`. 3) specify your output and expected output.

Comment: I added a comment showing the the MVE case doesn't have this issue. so my best guess is some memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate all the help I got from you folks, and decided to return to this today and found the issue. As far as I can tell it's a compiler flag issue where the compiler/preprocessor takes the concatentation operator (//) as a c++ comment and the preprocessor comments everything out after the concatenation. I had to use continuation ampersands to kludge together a fix, but it works for now, and then I can look into the flags another time. If anyone has any insight though, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: To avoid this, cpp is run in the traditional mode by gfortran and Intel uses a modified fpp.

Comment: @VladimirF could you elaborate? I don't understand.

Comment: Those preprocessors do not discard `//`.

Comment: How do I use those preprocessors?

Comment: By using `gfortran -cpp`,   `ifort -fpp`, by using these compilers with file names `.F90` or `.F` or by calling `fpp` explicitly or by calling `cpp -traditional-cpp` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the posted routine using this test program:

- I couldn't find issues with gfortran>=5.3.0, but it is my experience that gfortran's string handling has been pretty buggy in the past versions;
- my coding practice whenever I have variable-size strings is to have a fixed-length string buffer (say, `character(len=BUFFER_SIZE) :: buffer`), to do all temporary cut and paste, and then assign the relevant portion to a variable-length variable at the end of the function (choose the max length with grain of salt!)
- in the attached example, I've posted a sample path creation function. It may be generalized for more flexible usage (choice of folder name, etc.);

```
program test_string
   implicit none
   
   integer :: counter
   character(len=:), allocatable :: fileName
   
   counter = 2
   
   ! Original routine   
   call create_string_orig(counter,'PLT/Solution')
   
   ! With path function
   fileName = output_fileName('PLT',counter)
   write(*,*) 'filename with function: ', fileName
   
   contains
   
   function output_fileName(folder,iter) result(fileName)
      character(*), intent(in) :: folder      
      integer, intent(in) :: iter
      character(len=:), allocatable :: fileName
      
      ! Local variables 
      character(*), parameter :: prefix = 'Solution'
      character(*), parameter :: ext    = '.plt'
      character(len=1024) :: buffer
      character(len=6)    :: fileID
      integer :: fullLen
      
      write(fileID,'(I6.6)') iter
      
      buffer = trim(adjustl(folder)) // filesep() // prefix // '_' // fileID // ext
      
      fullLen = len_trim(buffer)
      
      allocate(character(len=fullLen) :: fileName)
      fileName(1:fullLen) = buffer(1:fullLen)
      
   end function output_fileName
   
   ! Get current system's folder separator
   character function filesep()
      character(len=9999) :: system_path
      integer             :: i

      system_path = repeat(' ',len(system_path))
      call get_environment_variable('PATH',system_path)

      do i = 1, len(system_path)
         if (system_path(i:i) == '/') then
            filesep = '/'
            return
         elseif (system_path(i:i) == '\') then
            filesep = '\'
            return
         endif
      end do

      ! Use default if unable to find a separator
      filesep = '/'
      return

   end function filesep   
   
   
   subroutine create_string_orig(iter,output_file)
      integer, intent(in) :: iter
      character(*), intent(in) :: output_file
      
      character(80) :: filename,file_num
       
      write(file_num,'(I6.6)') iter
      write(*,*) 'output_name: ', output_file
      filename = adjustl(trim(output_file)) // '_' // adjustl(trim(file_num)) // '.plt'
      write(*,*) 'filename1: ', filename
      filename = adjustl(trim(filename))
      write(*,*) 'filename2: ', filename
      print*,'# Writing to File...', iter
      
      end subroutine create_string_orig
end program
```

That produces the following output (working on Windows):

```
$ a.exe
 output_name: PLT/Solution
 filename1: PLT/Solution_000002.plt
 filename2: PLT/Solution_000002.plt
 # Writing to File...           2
 filename with function: PLT\Solution_000002.plt
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using ifort, are you aware of any issues with that?